# jEditable & DataTables - Table wont refresh on update

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

I am using jQuery DataTables with the jEditable plugin installed. I have everything working correctly, the table renders and pulls data correctly. The table is editable and the script is correctly updating the backend DB. The only issue is the value gets updated then the cell is empty until you hit refresh then the new value is visible.

I have tried to incorporate fnDraw into the callback so that it will redraw the table but I am unable to figure it out? The only I thing I am missing is to have the table dynamically refreshed after a new value is written to the DB.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
/* Init DataTables */
var oTable = $('#district').dataTable();

/* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
$('#district', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable( 'lib/editable_ajax.php', {
    tooltip   : 'Click cell to edit value...',
    indicator : 'Saving...',
    style   : 'display:block;',
     submit    : 'OK',
     cancel    : 'Cancel',
     data   : " {'PDC 30':'PDC 30','PDC 14':'PDC 14','PDC 81':'PDC 81','PDC 58':'PDC 58'}",
     type    : 'select',
    "Callback": function( sValue, x) {
        var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
        oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);

        /* Redraw the table from the new data on the server */
        oTable.fnClearTable( 0 );
        oTable.fnDraw();
    },
    "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
        var aPos2 = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
        var id2 = oTable.fnGetData( aPos2[0] ); 
        return {
            "row_id": this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'),
            "id2": id2[0],
            "column": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[ 2 ]         
        };
    },
    "height": "14px",
} );
} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try initialising the variable oTable outside the function and see, though this should not make any difference as your code looks fine.